# Saving Roster for Offline/Disconnects proposes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xmpp, xmppframework

I downloaded the SampleProject off XMPPFramework for iOS and connected it already to my Jabber Server. Everything ok.

But I would like to have my Buddys to stay in the Buddys overview even if I have been disconnected (Connection lost). Is that possible? As I understood the XMPPCoreStorage save them in CoreData. Why do it get cleaned at a disconnect? Is it possible to disable the clean at disconnect? I unfornatly didnt found the method.

Would be really annoying & much traffic if it isnt persistent or?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I came up with a solution:

On the XMPPRoster.m xmppStreamDidDisconnect:

i commented 4 lines out. It looks now like this:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
{
    // This method is invoked on the moduleQueue.

    XMPPLogTrace();

//  [xmppRosterStorage clearAllUsersAndResourcesForXMPPStream:xmppStream];
//  
//  [self _setRequestedRoster:NO];
//  [self _setHasRoster:NO];
//  
//  [earlyPresenceElements removeAllObjects];
}
```

So it will not clear the storage on a disconnect. On a reconnect it will clean and refill the storage with updated information. Hope it helps other people. Its not a perfect solution . A preffered one is to build your own CoreData model & fetch the XMPP stuff in there..

Comment: in the new Version there are: xmppRoster.autoClearAllUsersAndResources = NO;